# Android parse.com listView crashing

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

i am attempting to create this app which has a listView and when i click on an item in the listView it displays more information about the clicked item. I dont know how to fix this problem. i am  getting the following from my log

```
   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                        at com.example.velvetdev01.parselistclick.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:50)
                                                                                        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
```

and here is my code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQueryAdapter;

import java.util.List;

//import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {


private CustomAdapter urgentTodosAdapter;
private ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> mainAdapter;
private ListView listView;
List<ParseObject> object;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview);

    mainAdapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(this, "RestaurantDetail");
    urgentTodosAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    listView.setAdapter(urgentTodosAdapter);
    urgentTodosAdapter.loadObjects();


    // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
    listView.setAdapter(urgentTodosAdapter);
    // Capture button clicks on ListView items
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            // Send single item click data to SingleItemView Class
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SingleItemView.class);
            // Pass data "name" followed by the position
            intent.putExtra("Name", object.get(i).getString("Name"));
            // Open SingleItemView.java Activity
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

}
```

and my custom adapter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.parse.ParseFile;
import com.parse.ParseImageView;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.ParseQueryAdapter;


public class CustomAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> {

public CustomAdapter(Context context) {

    super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {

        public ParseQuery create() {
            ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("RestaurantDetail");

 /* query.whereEqualTo("Name", true);*/

            return query;
        }
    });
}
@Override
public View getItemView(ParseObject object, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (v == null) {

        v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.activity_main, null);
    }
    super.getItemView(object, v, parent);

    ParseImageView todoImage = (ParseImageView)     v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    ParseFile imageFile = object.getParseFile("Logo");
    if (imageFile != null) {
        todoImage.setParseFile(imageFile);
        todoImage.loadInBackground();
    }

    TextView titleTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    titleTextView.setText(object.getString("Name"));
    return v;
}
}
```

Here is the class i am trying to display the detailed information

```
 @ParseClassName("RestaurantDetail")
 public class SingleItemView extends Activity {

 // Declare Variables
 protected TextView txtname;
 String Name;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from singleitemview.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.single_item_view);

    txtname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);

    // Retrieve data from MainActivity on item click event
    Intent random1 = getIntent();
    // Get the name
    Name = random1.getStringExtra("Name");

    // Locate the TextView in singleitemview.xml
    txtname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);


    // Load the text into the TextView
    txtname.setText(Name);

}
}
```

Comment: Could you post your `CustomAdapter` code? Your `List<ParsedObject>object` hasn't been initialized anywhere in the given code and hence it is null, which is causing null pointer exception. When you will be setting value to this object?

Comment: Guruprasad Rao, i can't say i understand what you are saying. i am new to android, could you please help out

Comment: Definitely I'll be helping. The exception here is pretty straight forward. You see `List<ParseObject> object;` defined in your `MainActivity`? I hope you should be getting this exception during on click of list item  on `intent.putExtra("Name", object.get(i).getString("Name"));` line.. To do `object.get(i)`, you need to initialize your `List<ParseObject> object;` with `List<ParseObject> object=new ArrayList<>();` and then you need to set add some value to that list..

Comment: it is crashing on that line, i put a break point on it too.

Comment: do i populate the arrayList in the MainActivity?

Comment: That I am not sure as it is not clear about your requirement, but the reason for your crash is what I mentioned in my last comment...

Comment: Guruprasad Rao, Thank you for your assistance mate, It helped a lot. Works now. it crashes but now i think where and how. (IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0)

Comment: That means you don't have any value in your `object` but still you are trying to get `item 0` from array.. Before you fetch any value from array, check its size as in `if(object.size()>0)` kind of..

Comment: Guruprasad Rao can you please assist me one final time. the Intent runs but i am still getting nothin in the end. The log doesn't show the index as 0 anymore but still it doesn't display any values from parse. Your help would be much appretiated

Comment: Its very difficult for me to assist you unless and until I know how you are getting your list filled.. Let me know if you have any ways to direct interaction to look into the project if you insist..

Comment: Guruprasad Rao . I am using values i am getting from my parse class.
The custom adapter queries data from parse from a class called "RestaurantDetail", from there i get the name and picture of the restaurant and i am able to put in a listView that i declared in my MainActivity. 
From there i want to be able to click on one of the items on the listView and get detail information about the restaurant (ie, Logo, Name, address, type of food etc) and display it using texViews.

Comment: So you are getting your data set in listview?

Comment: Guruprasad Rao, Yes my data is set in a listView, the problem is when i press an item on the listView and it does not display the details of the item in the next screen

Comment: What will be stored in `object.get(i).getString("Name"))`

Comment: Guruprasad Rao  Thats the name i should get from the database

Comment: Guruprasad Rao  the class SingleItemView is the one i am trying to display the name, address, etc. First i need the name to display into the other then i can get the image and other textViews working

Comment: Guruprasad Rao are you still able to help me out with this unique problem??

Comment: Guruprasad Rao . ok, when do you have time??

Comment: Guruprasad Rao . ok works well with me

Comment: Guruprasad Rao yes i am here, i will mail in 10mins. computer a bit slow